# Почему не всегда отрабатывает выход клиента websocket?

Tags: node.js

Помогите разобраться с кодом. Не всегда срабатывает отключение клиента. Как можно сделать что бы срабатывало всегда? Три простых действия подключение клиента, отключение клиента, и отправка на север если клиент открыл вторую вкладку или запустил в другом браузере под тем же id. Помогите улучшить код. Сам новичок в этом так что простите за кривизну написанного))) Соединение клиента всегда отрабатывает на отлично а вот выход нет

```
ws.on('close', function() {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(userId), 1);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(clients.indexOf(userId)===-1 ){
            wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
                if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    client.send(JSON.stringify({'disconnect': userId, "roomOut": room}));
                }
            });
            exitUser(userId).then(function (user) {});
        }
    },10000)
});
if (clients.indexOf(userId) >= 0) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({'disconnec':userId}));
        }
    });
}
if (clients.indexOf(userId) === -1) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            client.send(JSON.stringify({'connected': userId, "roomNew": room}));
        }
    });
}
ws.send(JSON.stringify({'connected': userId, "roomNew": room}));
clients.push(userId);
```